# imbalanced numeric target variable in machine learning

Tags: regression, machine-learning, unbalanced-classes

In the machine learning problem I'm trying to solve, the target variable is numeric.(Integers 0, 1, 2, 3, ... 25. However, they are highly imbalanced. There are more than 20k of 0s, 1500 of 1s,  600 of 2s, 180 of 3s, 84 of 4s, ......
My question is what is the proper way to deal with this kind of machine learning regression problem? High appreciate if anyone can give me expert advice. Thanks.

Comment: This depends on what you're modelling.  We would need more context in order to be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I might need more context of your problem statement, and what kind of models you might be working on, but usually the concept that I use to deal with imbalanced target data is ***sampling***.

There are a number of Minority and Majority Sampling methods e.g., *SMOTE*, *RandomUnderSampler*, *RandomOverSampler*.

Minority sampling methods are used to oversample the minority classes in the target data, whereas majority sampling techniques are used to undersample the majority class in the target data.

[You can check out this link regarding different sampling techniques](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-class-imbalanced-classification/)

*PS*: *Studies have shown that the **combination of oversampling and undersampling** the target data has produced better results than oversampling the minority class, or undersampling a majority class*.